# Python zip unzip progress bar

Tags: python-3.x

I have a PyQt5 application that does zip/unzip operations under the hood and a general progress bar that indicates the status.
For example: if I download a file, I can track the `received_bytes & total_size` and calculate the current percentage.
The same can be done for the `zip` since it has a `for` loop and I can calculate the amount of processed files.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(f'{path}', 'w') as z:
  for file in files:
    z.write(file_path, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_STORED)
```

I would like to know is it possible for me somehow to track the progress of the `unpack` operation?

```
shutil.unpack_archive(path_from, path_to)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a solution with the `ZipFile`

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

class ZipFileCustom(ZipFile):
    """ Custom ZipFile class with a callback on extractall. """

    def extractall(self, path=None, members=None, pwd=None, fn_progress=None):
        if members is None:
            members = self.namelist()

        if path is None:
            path = os.getcwd()
        else:
            path = os.fspath(path)

        for index, member in enumerate(members):
            if fn_progress:
                fn_progress(len(members), index + 1)
            self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
```

As you can see I've added the `fn_progress` into the `extractall` and a bit modified its `for` loop.
Now can use this method together with the function to calculate percents:

```
def calculate_percentage(total: int, current: int):
    percent = float(current) / total
    percent = round(percent * 100)
    return percent

with ZipFileCustom('./test.zip') as zfc:
    zfc.extractall('./out', fn_progress=lambda total, current: print(f'{calculate_percentage(total, current)} %'))
```

The output is:

```
4%
8%
12%
17%
...
88%
92%
96%
100%
```